# How is Pandas dataframe records filtering notation implemented?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working through a Pandas tutorial, and I'm seeing code like:

```
from pandas import read_csv
dataset = read_csv('customers.csv')

# remove customers older than 95
dataset = dataset[dataset.age < 95]
```

I'm wondering what this operation is, and how it's implemented in Python?  It looks like data frames can accept dict notation (`dataset['age']`), as well as this notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `dataset.age < 95` will produce a `Series` with the the indexes of the `dataset` and the values will be the result of the value associated with that index compared to `< 95`. If you use this result to select something in a dataframe, it will return the rows in which indexes in the series have value `True`.

For example:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list(range(5)), 'b': list(range(5, 10))})

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   a  b
0  0  5
1  1  6
2  2  7
3  3  8
4  4  9

In [3]: type(df.a < 3)
Out[3]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [4]: df.a < 3
Out[4]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Both notations `df.column_name` and `df['column_name']` are valid and equivalent, but it is not possible to to use, for example, `df.column name` in that case use `df['column name']`. In general, `df.column_name` can be use when `column_name` is a valid identifier, and it will not have the same name as any method or field defined for `type(df)`.